# Timestamp quantity for PDF long time archive

Tags: signature, pki, timestamping

How many timestamps are issued when someone signs a PDF with timestamp Long Term Archive (LTA)? Why is it necessary to issue more than one timestamp?

Comment: I've altered your question somewhat as asking for resources such as a web page is generally considered off topic.

Comment: That's ok, thanks